# How does the entropy of an isolated system increase?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

The change of entropy is defined $$\Delta S = \int \frac{dQ_\mathrm{rev}}{T}.$$  If a system is isolated the heat transfer between the system and the surroundings is zero ($dQ = 0$), thus $\Delta S = 0$.

However, it is commonly stated that the entropy of an isolated system can increase.  How is this possible, given the above definition of entropy?

Comment: Closely related (Liouville theorem VS entropy increase) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/761468/226902

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of entropy $$dS = \frac{\delta Q}{T}$$ only applies for reversible processes.  For every irreversible process, $$dS > \frac{\delta Q}{T}.$$  Therefore, if the sytem is isolated ($\delta Q = 0$), and an irreversible process occurs, $dS > 0$.

Simple irreversible processes include friction, mixing, and heat transfer accross a finite temperature difference.

Answer (score 6):

One reason is that different parts of the system can be at different temperatures. If a part of the system at $T_1$ transfers an amount $\Delta Q$ of heat to a part of the system at $T_2<T_1$, the hot part's entropy changes by

$$\Delta S_\text{(hot)} = -\frac{\Delta Q}{T_1}$$

but the entropy of the cold part changes by

$$\Delta S_\text{(cold)} = \frac{\Delta Q}{T_2},$$

so the total entropy change is

$$\Delta S = \Delta S_\text{(cold)} + \Delta S_\text{(hot)} = \Delta Q \left( \frac{1}{T_2}  - \frac{1}{T_1} \right) > 0. $$

Another reason, as 
Ignacio Vergara Kausel pointed out, is that entropy changes can also occur for other reasons than heat flow. For example, chemical reactions can change a system's composition, which affects its entropy.

Comment: sorry for a comment on such an old post, but I wanted to clarify something - the equation you wrote down for a simple isolated system cannot be further simplified, right? I mean for instance in an isothermal process, I could write $dq$ as $dw=pdV$ and integrate to find the entropy change, but a similar thing cannot be done here, can it?

Comment: @GRrocks I'm not quite sure what you mean. I don't think the equations I wrote down can be simplified, because they come directly from the (phenomenological) definition of entropy. However, if you wanted to express them as differentials and then integrate you could do that, as long as you know the heat capacity. Does that help?

Comment: actually I was given a problem in an exam which asked me to calculate the change in entropy of an isolated system, without any other information about the system. So, I just wrote down that it would be nonnegative , that's the most general thing I could think of. But the TA who is grading the papers apparently did this- he wrote down $dq=pdV=RT/V dV$ for subsystems (I am guessing he assumed that the subsystems don't change their energy), and then integrated for the entropy. I don't agree with the use of this $pdV$ , and I cannot really think of any system where this happens. Can you explain?

Comment: @GRrocks I don't think I can answer that without knowing more specifics about the problem. Your best bet is to post it as a new question. (Be aware of the homework policy though - make sure you focus on the conceptual issue, not on how to solve the specific problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Because that's not the whole picture and the entropy of a system can change by other means. A more complete picture can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Entropy_and_other_forms_of_energy_beyond_work).

Answer (score 0):

An isolated body in vacuum  will radiate continuously and loose energy  by the [black body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation) radiation :

j is the total power per unit area radiated away

[image]

and as it radiates it cools. An estimate of the time taken for cooling is [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/cootime.html#c1).

The law that  entropy increases or stays constant can be applied only to closed systems. The closed system  in this case is the body radiating + all the photons radiated. The entropy of the body decreases, but the whole system's entropy increases since the  number of infrared  is enormous  and continually increasing. The [statistical expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Statistical_mechanics) of entropy is applicable here, and not the thermodynamic one, because the system body+radiation does not have one temperature.

It is worth noting that the entropy of an isolated body cooling with black body radiation decreases for the body. If it is made of crystallizable material  it will crystallize and be highly ordered. The same is true for all living matter. A cell lives by continually decreasing its own entropy, but raising the entropy of cell+surroundings.